# How to create a new state object instead of mutating an existing one?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi all i am having a state

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({})

const handleClick = () => {

    let newObject = { 'name':'ironman'} 

    setValue(newObject);
}
```

here onClick i am calling this `handleClick` function. and updating the state value with newObject. Am i mutating the state? or how can i create a newState object without mutating the existing one? Any help or suggestions is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i understand correct, you want to add new object into value variable without making any changes on existing object so the value of value variable look like following : {{}, {name:"ironman}}, am is correct ?

Comment: no..i want to replace the state with ```newObject``` . ```intialState = {}``` after setState it should be ```{ 'name':'ironman'} ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you generate new state by

```
value.name = 'ironman';
setValue(value);
```

This is what you mean by *create a newState object **with** mutating the existing one*. Such code is mutating state while code in question is not.

To create newState object without mutating the existing one, just clone it. It might be tricky for deep object trees. For simple object containing one level property (I usually design state like that), just

```
const newState = {...value, {prop: newValue}};
setValue(newState)
```

Following https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables, it's better to define multiple state variable for different properties.